# empty list when return from a function c++ encapsulated in object

Tags: c++, list

I have a class that encapsulates a std::list in c++

```
class A {
string toSelect;
list<CustomObject1> lst;
list<CustomObject2> lst1;
}
```

I have another class `Process` that returns object A in one of it's methods.

```
A Process::do() {
// ...
// ...
CustomObject1 cust = CustomObject1(para1,para2);
list<CustomObject1> c;

CustomObject2 cust2 = CustomObject2(para3,para4);
list<CustomObject2> c2;

c2.push_back(cust2);
c.push_back(cust)

return A("abc", c, c2);
```

When i do unit tests in cpp unit test framework however, the content in the list becomes empty immediately.

```
namespace UnitTesting
{
    TEST_CLASS(TestMethod)
    {
    public:


    TEST_METHOD(TestDo) {
    Process* process = new Process();
    A a = process->do();
    Assert::AreEqual(a.lst.size(),1) // a.lst is empty
    }
}
```

How do i get the list inside object A to be populated in this manner ?

**Edit**

A.h

```
A(string toSelect, list<CustomObject1> custObjs, 
    list<CustomObject2> custObjs1)
```

A.cpp

```
A::A(string toSelect, list<CustomObject1> custObjs, 
list<CustomObject2> custObjs1)
{
    this->toSelect = toSelect;
    this->custObjs = custObjs;
    this->custObjs1 = custObjs;
}
```

this is the full definition for A.

Comment: If you're using c++11 or above. I think this is not a problem. If you're using older c++ version, the reason is you returning a copied object. And the copy is not a deep copy. Also, you might be passing `c` to `A(c)` by reference. `c` is destroyed when `Process` is exited.

Comment: Hmm, i think im using c++ 11 and above. I am using visual studio 2019 version

Comment: c is a list which is dynamically created in the heap ? would it be destroyed after returning from the function process ?

Comment: can you give the constructor for `A`? maybe that's where the cause of the problem is.

Comment: added the constructors in the post

Comment: seems correct. unless `lst` is a real member name on `A` and as we see it, it is not set in the constructor. so it is empty.

Comment: what do u mean by real member name ?

Comment: on your example code, the onlly defined member in class `A` is `lst`. but in your constructor, the name of the list type members are `custObjs` and `custObjs1`.

Comment: Please provide a minimal but complete example.

Comment: If I was debugging this, one of the first things I would verify is that the lists are not empty just before `Process::do()` returns.

Comment: Yes the lists were not empty before return. It is only during the construction of the list that the list within the A object became empty.

Comment: @acegs A `std::list` copy will never change the `size()`, even if the element type fails to implement deep copying. I doubt the version of C++ standard has much to do with this.

Comment: @calveeen In that case, please provide a [mre] that demonstrates that the list is not empty before returning and that the list is empty after returning. (You don't need a fancy assertion, just stream the size to `cout`.) The current form of your code is too haphazard to compile. I cannot tell which mistakes come from you slashing the code and which are present in the actual code. (Once I worked around the compiler errors, the list was not empty after returning.)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by declaring the `list<CustomObject1> lst;` to a `list<CustomObject*> *lst` where `*lst` is a pointer to a list and each element in a list is a pointer to a pointer to a custom object. That way when i call the constructor

```
A::A(string toSelect, list<CustomObject1*> *custObjs, 
list<CustomObject2*> *custObjs1)
{
    this->toSelect = toSelect;
    this->custObjs = custObjs;
    this->custObjs1 = custObjs;
}
```

I am assigning the attribute `custObjs` to point to the list that was created inside A::process() method.

Not sure whether I would have to do a clean up manually for this. Would anyone know whether it needs to be done ?

Comment: This makes the class harder to use correctly and harder to implement correctly. I'd avoid the pointers and try to track down the original bug.

Comment: following the A.cpp constructor in the post (not the solution), the bug comes in the constructor when i try to call this->custObjs = custObjs, the list<CustomerObject> custObjs parameter contains the right size, but when this->custObjs = custObjs was executed the resulting custObjs list in class A had 0 elems.

Comment: How does changing the declaration of `lst` affect a constructor that does not make use of `lst`? Suddenly switching from calling the member `lst` to calling it `custObjs` is just one of the many inconsistencies in the question's code.

Comment: @JaMiT hey JaMiT. I have tried to run the code on my computer, indeed i am able to run it upon fixing the inconsistencies and have the expected sizes. Upon changing some parts in the original code ( this was a disguised version ). I am able to get the expected answer. I apologise for the unorganised code that I had posted earlier in desperation, and thank you for trying to help as well !